# integral operator with continuous integrable function

Tags: operator-theory, integral-operators

Let $k: [0,\infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and

$\int_{0}^{\infty} |k(x)|dx < + \infty$.

Set

$(Af)(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} k(x+y) f(y) dy, f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Show that $A$ is bounded and compact. Arzela-Ascoli seems a reasonable guess with regards to the latter, but what about the former? Why is this integral even $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $Af(-x)$ is the convolution of $f$ and $k_1(t)=k(-t)$. Use the inequality $\|f*g\|_2 \leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_1$.

Ref. See the heading Integrable Functions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Comment: Extend $k$ to the negative half line by letting $k=0$ for $x \in (-\infty,0)$ (and $f$ if so need be: I intended $f \in L^2([0,\infty))$ and note:

$Af(-x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k_1(x-y)f(y) dy$, $\ k_1(x)=k(-x), \ x \in \mathbb{R}$. Inequality:

$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \big |\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  k_1(x-y)f(y) dy \big |^2 dx \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \big |\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  k_1(x-y)f(y) dy \big |^2 dx = ||k_1 \ast f||_2 \leq ||k||_1||f||_2$.

Comment: This what you had in mind?

Comment: I am confused now, moving to the second question. Having rewritten it as a convolution, shouldnt that contradict the second statement? And is AA even the right approach?

Comment: Somewhat related perhaps: 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302599/is-this-integral-operator-on-l-20-infty-compact

Comment: The operator $A$ is bounded:

$||Af||_2^2 \\ =\int_{0}^{\infty} |\int_{0}^{\infty} k(x+y)f(y) dy|^2 dx \\ \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} (\int_{0}^{\infty} |k(x+y)||f(y)| dy)^2 dx \\ \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} |k(x+y)| dy \int_{0}^{\infty} |k(x+y)||f(y)|^2 dy dx \\ \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} |k(y)| dy \int_{0}^{\infty}  |f(y)|^2\int_{0}^{\infty} |k(x+y)|dx dy \\ \leq ||k||_1^2 ||f||_2^2$.

Comment: And the operator is compact: we can define a family of piecewise smooth functions on $[0,\infty)$  for a corresponding family of integral operators that are compact on $L^2([0,\infty))$ and that converges to A.